# Airflow Browser UI not detecting imported Module

Tags: python, linux, airflow

Through a Linux server, I am running Airflow with Docker compose. Other DAGs created with .py scripts work fine. Other python scripts creating DAGS that import different modules will run fine and show up in the DAG list.

However, importing the modules below within my Launch.py results in a `Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/ScanLaunchDemo.py] No module named 'tenable_io'`.

Ironically, Launch.py runs perfectly fine within the Linux instance and within a python terminal (the 'no tenable_io' error does not show). It seems like only Airflow cannot 'detect' the module below.

```
from tenable_io.client import TenableIOClient
from tenable_io.api.scans import ScanCreateRequest
from tenable_io.api.models import ScanSettings
```

Running pip3 list will show that tenable-io is installed.

Thanks for the helps peeps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily for me, I rewrote the API request such that it did not require a module that was not already built into Airflow. Jarek seems to be correct however, that for modules that don't come installed within airflow, a custom image will need to be created.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker Compose, then in order to make the module available to  airflow, you need to use custom image where you installed your own additional dependencies. We **just** updated the documentation make it clearer why you need it, and how to do it, including examples:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html